# Error when I try sending strings over intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an app in which many activities open another in which some things are set after the buttons that opened it(images, tags, etc.).After this activity is closed I want to be returned a string vith value "1" which will be converted to an int and used to set a score.

In activity that returns i have this:

```
Intent i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vie);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

        win_sound = MediaPlayer.create(Vie.this, R.raw.win);
        wrong_sound= MediaPlayer.create(Vie.this, R.raw.wrong);

        i = getIntent();
        Bitmap back = i.getParcelableExtra("back");
        Drawable b = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), back);
        img.setImageDrawable(b);
        String tag = i.getStringExtra("tag");
        Object tag2 = (Object) tag;
        img.setTag(tag2);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean mb = check(et, img);
        if (mb) {
            // Sunet toast thread
            txt.setText(title(img));
            win_sound.start();
            i.putExtra("score", "1");
            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

            Thread t = new Thread() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.run();
                    try {
                        sleep(win_sound.getDuration());

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        finish();
                    }

                }

            };

            t.start();

        }

        if (!mb) {
            // sunet toast thread
            wrong_sound.start();
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong answer! Please check if you have spelled corectly the name of the team!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
        }
    }
```

And the OnActivityResult methode:

```
int a = 0
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (data.getExtras().containsKey("score")) {
            a +=Integer.valueOf(data.getStringExtra("score")); 
        }

    }
```

and a textView is set to show a:

txtScore.setText(a);

But this gives me an error, this is my LogCat:

```
06-29 15:28:25.312: E/AndroidRuntime(981): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
06-29 15:28:25.312: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:230)
06-29 15:28:25.312: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3769)
06-29 15:28:25.312: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at com.RandDdev.uclquiz.Teams.onCreate(Teams.java:61)
```

Could you help me?

Comment: post relevant codes... What is at the line of Team class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try txtScore.setText(""+a);
You cannot set an int directly to TextView

Answer (score 2):

```
txtScore.setText(a);
```

a is a `Integer`. So Android is looking for a String inside R with that id.

change with

```
txtScore.setText(String.valueOf(a));
```

you are using [setText(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29), instead of [setText(Charsequence)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

Comment: Note the different [setText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) methods in the docs

Comment: you are always so quick to answer. :). super quick

Comment: Nah, not his usual 33 seconds ;)

Comment: :) @codeMagic thanks for the [setText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) link

Comment: no problem...you won't let me answer questions so I can only comment :P @Raghunandan Ha, I sure did, I think that was a record

Answer (score 2):

You should use the below

```
   txtScore.setText(String.valueOf(a));
```

`public final void setText (int resid)`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

So it will look for a resource id which is an int value. This does not exist. Hence you get Resource not found exception